# kendo ui stacked bar chart datasource grouped not in order

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I've created a Stacked bar chart with Kendo ui, here: http://jsfiddle.net/Came19xx/t06zq2nr/4/

my problem is that chart put values not in order.
In my Datasource, i have an "open" and a "suspended" value, like that:

```
var data2 = [{"name":"abc","num":1,"state":"open"},
{"name":"abc","num":1,"state":"suspended"},
{"name":"def","num":2,"state":"open"},
{"name":"def","num":5,"state":"suspended"},
{"name":"ghi","num":3,"state":"open"},
{"name":"ghi","num":21,"state":"suspended"},
{"name":"jkl","num":4,"state":"open"},
{"name":"jkl","num":9,"state":"suspended"},
{"name":"mno","num":5,"state":"open"},
{"name":"mno","num":5,"state":"suspended"},
{"name":"pqr","num":6,"state":"open"},
{"name":"pqr","num":14,"state":"suspended"},
{"name":"stu","num":7,"state":"open"},
{"name":"stu","num":6,"state":"suspended"},
{"name":"vwxyz","num":8,"state":"open"},
{"name":"vwxyz","num":5,"state":"suspended"}];
```

So i grouped by state the datasource, but i don't get the open value corresponding to the name on the barchart and i can't sort it by name cause it will stop working.

For example, i want that abc is in the first line, with 1 in the left side (orange) of the stacked bar and 2 on the right side (red), instead i got vwxyz with the correct suspended value (5) and the wrong open value (3 instead of 8)

the "name" field and the "num" field may can change their value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding name as a sort field on the datasource:

```
dataSource: {
    data: data2,
    group: [{
        field: "state",
        dir: "desc"
    }],
    sort: {
        field: "name",
        dir: "asc"
    }
}
```

Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t06zq2nr/5/)**

Comment: Now more difficult... it were asked to me to sort chart by num values... There is a way to sort it only by suspended value and get the corresponding open value on the same "line"?
Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Came19xx/g6rdnk7q/3/)
@ezanker

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!